# How pass JsonArray in flutter post request?

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, flutter-dependencies

I Have request like

```
    {"criteriaList": [{"key":"UserId","value":238,"match":"ExactMatch"},{"key":"TenantOid","value":9999,"match"
:"ExactMatch"}]}
```

I want to post this request, but while calling api I am getting 'Bad Request'.

I am using http library.

What I tried for now is

```
     var data =
        "{\"criteriaList\": [{\"key\":\"UserId\",\"value\":$userId,\"match\":\"ExactMatch\"},{\"key\":\"TenantOid\",\"value\":$tenantId,\"match\":\"ExactMatch\"}]}";
    var body =
        jsonEncode(data);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first one looks ok, you just encode this without backsplash

Comment: just try to encode the map as is, i dont think you need to turn it into a string nor add the backslashes

Comment: @JahidulIslam I tried that way also, but still facing same error. JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.portfolio.dto.PortFolioSearchCriteria` (although at least one Creator exists)